# How to pass an expression into JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object, parameter-passing

I have 2 classes objects: `let a, let b`, and each object has a key 'value'.
I want to be able to create third object `let c` and calculate it's 'value' key like this: `c.value = a.value + b.value`.
Here's the question:

I need value of `let c` to change when values of `a` or `b` change. `let c` may be a different class with key 'dependencies', where I pass arguments of the equation and then a function which updates `c.value` every time `dependency.value` changes. But I still should be able to pass signs such as '+', '-', '*' etc.

Code example:

```
class Data{
    name: string;
    value: number;

  constructor(name, value){
      this.name = name;
      this.value = value;
  }

class Calc{
    name: string;
    value: number;
    dependencies: Array<object>;

  constructor(name, dep){
    this.name = name;
    this.dependencies = dep;
  }

let a = new Data('a', 10)
let b = new Data('a', 7)

let c = new Calc('c', [a, b])
```

And I need to be able to pass a complete expression like `c.value = a.value - b.value * d.value` into object in order for this to be flexible.

How can it be done in JavaScript? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A specific example of the code you're working with would clarify things significantly

Comment: at a guess, Proxy **may** help - though I'm not 100% sure about your last statement - as above, even if it has to be pseudo code, something that better describes your objective may help

Comment: Possibly something like making `c` a class and `value` a getter, which calculates the value every time you access it. Generally, no, you can't "assign an expression to a variable".

Comment: Take a look at [How to Build Your Own Reactivity System](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-build-your-own-reactivity-system-fc48863a1b7c)

Comment: You can look into rxJs for observer pattern. This way you can listen to changes in value and add dependencies dynamically

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: what do you mean with "*I need to be able to pass a complete expression*"?

Comment: @NinaScholz, I need to pass an equation explicitly. like  a + b - c into an object

Comment: do you have a consistent example?

Comment: As mentioned before, you can look into `rxjs`. Following is a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/9qd2mLwj/15/)

Answer (score -1):

We can pass expression as arguments into function by following way.

```
function calculation(expression){
 if(expression == '+'){
    var output = 40 + 50;
 }else if(expression == '-'){
    var output = 40 - 50;
 }
 console.log(output);
}
calculation('+');
```